# Using @ViewChild in Angular `strict`mode

Tags: angular, angular-material

What is the common way to use `@ViewChild` in Angular strict mode?

For example, when I take the code for sorting a Material table as described in [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sorting)

```js
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;
```

The compiler says:

> error TS2564: Property 'sort' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

As a possible solution I could use

```js
@ViewChild(MatSort, { static: false }) sort!: MatSort;
```

... but that seems to me more like a workaround.

Comment: You can probably just make it optional instead (i.e. `sort?: MatSort`), which will at least make you check that it's actually there before using it (thus avoiding an error). I don't feel like there's really anything wrong with using `?` or `!`, but using `?` will force you to unwrap it before use, which is helpful.

Comment: @ChrisGilardi suggestion is better than using the non-null assertion operator (!). ViewChild is essentially a query on your view so you can't always guarentee it won't be undefined (or that future changes to your view won't make it undefined).

Comment: Unfortunately with `?` it might be undefined instead of just `null`, hence I could not assign it to my datasource.sort.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be correct to remomve the `{ static: false }` part. So a valid declaration for `sort` would be:

```js
@ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
```

Comment: the use of `{static:true}` is only to "ViewChild"s that they are **always** visible in the app