# How to initialise a stepper in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, initialization, mat-stepper

I have written this code in my typescript file.

```
  @ViewChild('stepper') stepper: MatStepper;
```

And it also has this,

```js
/** Dialog for uploading avails. */
@Component({
  selector: 'upload-avails-dialog',
  templateUrl: './upload_avails_dialog.ng.html',
  styleUrls: ['./upload_avails_dialog.scss'],
  providers: [
    {provide: STEPPER_GLOBAL_OPTIONS, useValue: {showError: true}},
    {provide: ALKALI_UPLOAD_HANDLER, useExisting: UploadsApiClient}
  ],
})
```

I want to use this stepper variable like:

```
this.stepper.next()
```

when I complete the execution of a function.

```
Property 'stepper' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts.sema(2564)
```

I do have a constructor,

```js
constructor(
      private readonly snackBar: MatSnackBar,
      private readonly argonCreateInputAvailSetService:
          CreateInputAvailSetApiClient,
      private readonly argonGetInputAvailSetService: V1ApiClient) {
    this.uploadDetails = {
      '@type': UPLOAD_REQUEST_PROTO_NAME,
      'uploadType':
          UploadFileMetadataUploadTypeEnum.AVAILS_IMPORT_UPLOAD_TYPE_1_7,
    };
    this.checkUploadedXLSXLoading = false;
    this.validationStage = this.processingStage.NOT_READY;
    this.submitStage = this.processingStage.NOT_READY;
    this.fileName = '';
  }
```

But, I don't kow how to initialise this variable `stepper`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68166065/using-viewchild-in-angular-strictmode

Comment: In sort use !:
`@ViewChild('stepper') stepper !: MatStepper;`